# How to get the date of the selected <td> in a calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need an idea and maybe a solution to get the date from the `<td>`s which are selected by mouse.

Heres my code, to select (until now its only a function to change the class) the TD:

```
    $(function () {
  var isMouseDown = false,
    isHighlighted;
  $("#schichtplan td")
    .mousedown(function () {
      isMouseDown = true;
      $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
      isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("highlight");
      return false; // prevent text selection
    })
    .mouseover(function () {
      if (isMouseDown) {
        $(this).toggleClass("highlight", isHighlighted);
      }
    });
  $(document)
    .mouseup(function () {
      isMouseDown = false;
    });
});
```

A screenshot from the calendar:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUD9M.jpg)

This is, how the days are displayed:

```
echo "<td class=\"td kal_standard_tag\"> - </td>";
```

*The "-" is displayed, because at this day is no entry for this user.*

Maybe I could add something like this and read it out with jQuery?

```
 timestamp=\"".$timestamp_tag."\"
```

My target: After selecting the days, the user has to use rightclick and a Dialog shows up where the user can add some informations and save it to a database.
But I dont know how to get the selected days... :(

Does anyone have an idea and maybe a solution for that?

Comment: Is the selected td the one with the 'highlight' class on it?

Comment: Yes, the user can select days with left mouseclick, then they become the "highlight" class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice to do such things is to add a data attribute. So you would add a timestamp or datestamp as you said. E.g.: `<td data-timestamp="1231232131">` and then get it with jQuery in an event with `$(this).data('timestamp')`.

Comment: Okay, but how can I get the timestamps from the selected td and put it e.g. into an array or something to process further in PHP?

Comment: You have to have a look at arrays in Javascript and then take the value from `$(this).data('timestamp')` and put it into it. Then you can send this data via AJAX to the server where you process the data as you want in PHP.

Comment: Sorry, i dont get it...
Aren't the timestamps in `$(this).data('timestamp')` not all timestamps from the table?! I only want the timestamps from the selected?!

Comment: If you call `$(this).data('timestamp')` inside a mousedown or click function `$(this)` is only the element you clicked. And with .data('timestamp') you get the data attribute with the name 'timestamp'.

Comment: ** inside a mousedown or click function **
Ah, there was the knot in my brain... ;)

Thank you very much!

Comment: If I want to fill the array with click and drag, only the latest timestamp will be in the array. 
As you can see here: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/7sbjj10u/)
And if I click on only one day - theres nothing in the array.
I think its on the .mousedown in the script. If the array will be started in this part, it wont work to select via mouseover :(

Comment: You have to define your array globally. If you define your array in the function then it's going to be available only in the function, and deleted after the execution of the function.

Comment: Great! Sometimes, it can be so easy... :D 
Thank you again :)